# Is there a single command to remove a package source and its signing key?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, postgresql

I added the postgresql package source to my Linux Mint system. I'm new to apt and was wondering if, instead of deleting the package source from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and the signing key from `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` with `rm`, there is some capability provided by `apt` to do both in one go. I would expect one to exist as this seems to me to be basic functionality and to reduce risk of user error (i.e. deleting the wrong source or key).

Also, please let me know the right way to remove a package source if `rm`ing the entries in `sources.list.d` and `trusted.gpg.d` is not the right way to go about that.